# Has anyone used smartwin (a Windows C++ GUI OS library)?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I am considering using [smartwin](http://smartwin.sourceforge.net/) for a Windows platform only C++ project but notice that there has not been a release for 18months since 2.0rc5 was released i.e. it appears that it is no longer maintained.

After playing with it seems pretty good, I like it's use of  templates, signals/slots (via boost) and it will meet the project needs but I would like some experiences of other users who are currently using it to help me weight it up?

Comment: never use library from dead projects.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) instead? I think it has a lot of the features you're looking for, and would be *much* better supported, both in developer tools and framework maturity.

Comment: Yes, but discounted simply because we'd have to commercially license it but as we'd use it on only 1 small C++ project it didn't make much sense. It would be no brainer if we where a C++ house. Just need a light weight and simple C++ GUI wrapper for Win32 platform hence smartwin.

Comment: Qt 4.5, to be released next month, will be LGPL'ed; no commercial license will be necessary for most users.

Answer (score 1):

"...we really don't need a full application framework or cross platform portability - just a lite Win32 GUI framework that can be easily added to an existing app "

That is exactly what Smartwin was created for. Combine that with the Sally IDE, and you'll have a complete RAD development environment that is fast compact and complete. Note that Google is currently using WTL for their Chrome browser, but Smartwin is even more efficient than WTL.

Smartwin Also has a library called Winelib that they hope will make this also a portable environment in the long term.

Personally, if you want to go portable, I'd go with wxWidgets. However, if you are planning for sure to stay with windows, I'd certainly give Smartwin++ a look.

I, myself, would use wxWidgets, as thats what I usually use and am used to, so thats kind just a personal choice.

Good Luck.
-Donald

Comment: "Smartwin is even more efficient than WTL." - I've heard that SmartWin uses `std::map` for message dispatch, over WTL's macros-expanding-to-WndProc. If so, it would be less efficient, not more. Can you clarify what you mean here, and provide some references?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org). It is mature, well supported library with lots of features.

Comment: We've looked at both Qt and wxWidget and whilst they are mature and solid we really don't need a full application framework or cross platform portability - just a lite Win32 GUI framework that can be easily added to an existing app which was why I was looking for feedback on smartwin specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Went for WTL in the end and that's been a pretty seamless and painless transition. Thanks for the comments and responses everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate++
http://www.ultimatepp.org/